# How i can retrieve the records from the ms crm 2011 offline through C# code?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Have a requirement to create and update the records from ms crm 2011 in a offline state,
can anyone help me

Comment: This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: @SonerGönül the question is written badly, but if I understand he wants to retrieve and update the records stored in the `Outlook Client for CRM 2011` when the client is working in Offline mode. In this case the question is good and also interesting.

Comment: If that's really what he wants, he should definitely alter his question.

Comment: You can always accept the answer, if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Download the [Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004).
[Here's a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx) for create and update.

Comment: I removed your advice because is a comment not connected to your answer, if you want you can rewrite as comment inside the question

Comment: @GuidoPreite Agreed, it shouldn't have been there. However, I'll repeat it here : a simple google query will probably give you quite some answers to your questions already.